# Passing HTML through JSON to a Web Service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, stringify

I'm using CKEditor to allow our users to create content (text with tables, images etc). I then want to take whatever they've entered and pass it back to an ASP.Net web service using JSON.

I'm using JSON.stringify to convert my JSON object into a string and then sending it to the web service using JQuery ajax.

However when I try to convert the JSON string on the server using Newtonsoft.JSON I get an error as what's been passed isn't a valid JSON string. It seems to be an issue with line breaks and quotes in the HTML I'm passing, I could replace these before using JSON.stringify but my worry is that the user could enter practically anything. I was hoping JSON.stringify would correctly format my JSON but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is there something else I could use that would keep my JSON string valid?

Comment: if you need to send html, why don't you send html instead of json?

Comment: JSON is used for the exchange of data structures. HTML isn't a datastructure.

Comment: I concur with @Th0rndike. But if you really have to send HTML in your JSON string you need to escape **double-quotes** and **CRLF**.

Comment: I had to pass the HTML as part of a JSON object as the object contained some other important information I needed to save the content. I can highly recommend this JSON parser: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/json

Answer (score 1):

The following JSON parser solved my problem:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/json

also found at

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/